# Initialize a vector of vector of strings in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a vector of vectors of strings in C++ and I'm not getting it; this is what my code looks like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> foo =
        {
            std::vector<std::string> ex,
            std::vector<std::string> bar,
        };
    }
```

When trying to compile it with GCC, the following output is given to me:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:6:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘ex’
 std::vector<std::string> ex,
                        ^~
example.cpp:6:28: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘ex’
example.cpp:5:2: note: to match this ‘{’
{
^
example.cpp:6:28: error: could not convert ‘{<expression error>}’ from                                                            ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’
std::vector<std::string> ex,
                        ^~
example.cpp: At global scope:
example.cpp:9:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
}
^
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't have declaration in a definition statement

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> foo = {{"hello", "world"}, {"foobar"}};` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565907/7982776
this answer might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the names in the initialiser list:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> foo =
    {
        std::vector<std::string>{}, // <- no name + added curly braces
        std::vector<std::string>{}  // <- no comma
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

another way:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> foo(2);
}
```

Comment: Or just `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> foo(2);`

Comment: huh, yes! fixed